# WindowBeforeRightClick doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the Microsoft Ax framer control to view the word document in the Visual C# Form.

After hosting (open) the Word document in the Ax framer control.

While right-click on the Word document, MS Word context menu is appearing.

I want to hide this pop up menu.

I set

```
`Word.Document wddoc = (Word.Document)axFramerControl1.ActiveDocument;
Word.Application wordApp = wddoc.Application;
wordApp.WindowBeforeRightClick += new ApplicationEvents4_WindowBeforeRightClickEventHandler(wordApp_WindowBeforeRightClick);`
```

to handle RightClick of Microsoft Word.

But the application doesn't run the `WindowBeforeRightClick` event.

What's the problem?

Comment: These are the kind of problems that caused DsoFramer to be removed completely over 4 years ago.  It will not come back.  Writing an add-in is the way forward.

Comment: Could you explain more about how I should use add-in for WindowBeforeRightClick?

Answer (score 1):

This was bug that was fixed with March 2016 update for Word 2016.

MS16-029: Description of the security update for Word 2016: March 8, 2016

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114855